# how to draw closed polygon on Altair chart

Tags: python, altair

How can I draw a closed polygon on Altair chart?

This does not... Thank you.

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


end_points = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        NEU=[0, 1, 0.3, 0],
        DEN=[2.65, 1, 2.5, 2.65],
    )
)


alt.Chart(end_points).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X("NEU"),
    y=alt.Y("DEN", scale=alt.Scale(domain=[3, 0])),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified, Altair sorts data by the x value before drawing lines. If you want a custom order, you can use the `order` channel, as demonstrated in the [Lines With Custom Paths](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/connected_scatterplot.html) example:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

end_points = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        NEU=[0, 1, 0.3, 0],
        DEN=[2.65, 1, 2.5, 2.65],
    )
)

alt.Chart(end_points.reset_index()).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X("NEU"),
    y=alt.Y("DEN", scale=alt.Scale(domain=[3, 0])),
    order='index'
)
```

[image]